# How should I get bodies to move at a constant speed across the ground in box2d?

Tags: box2d, libgdx

My current prototype-y hack is to take away the ground's friction, but now I want a real solution.

I figure I could just do some basic physics math and give each object an impulse every time step, but if that happens like 60 times a second, would it be kind of costly, computation-wise?

Is there a better way to set some kind of constant velocity on an object until some kind of outside force touches it ( in my case a projectile or wall)?

Comment: Ask over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read this article for your solution

[Constant speed](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/constant-speed)

We can apply constant speed by

> Setting velocity directly

```
body->SetLinearVelocity( vel );
```

> Using forces

```
body->ApplyForce( b2Vec2(force_x,force_y), body->GetWorldCenter() )
```

> Using impulses

```
 body->ApplyLinearImpulse( b2Vec2(impulse_x,impulse_y), body->GetWorldCenter() );
```

Comment: Link only answers are not complaint with the site rules. Links may change in the future, turning the answer useless.

Comment: FYI To set the velocity without altering the direction just normalize the current velocity then multiply it with the desired velocity. b2Vec2 v = body->GetLinearVelocity(); v.Normalize(); body->SetLinearVelocity(100.f * v);

Comment: @LaurentZubiaur What does 100.f mean? Is this a factor?

Answer (score 2):

[Body#setLinearVelocity](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.html#setLinearVelocity%28float,%20float%29)

Example:

```
body.setLinearVelocity(10, 0); //Right
```

That moves the body at a constant speed, just keep setting it before every step.